# After authenticating of user want to display the data belong to the current user

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm building a simple app using HTML/CSS/JS and Firebase. After authenticating the user, I want to display the data belonging to the current user. Is there the protected way to do this? I would appreciate some sample code. Thanks!

Comment: There are plenty of examples of code in the Firebase docs, specifically [these docs related to authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) and also [these docs related to reading/writing to the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write). You should try some things in there to get more comfortable. When you get stuck, feel free to post a specific question, but please follow these community guidelines/suggestions on [how to ask a question properly here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can check Firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/